# De que puede ser este error al ejecutar node con express?

Tags: nodejs, express, línea-de-comandos

Estoy queriendo ejecutar el servidor, pero me tira un error de sintaxis que no se de que es. Aclaro que no es mi codigo, es del profesor. Lo que hice fue instalar express al proyecto, junto con node. Pero por alguna razon no se porque me tira ese error. A lo mejor es algo sencillo que no veo, o quizas problemas con la version de node.

ARCHIVO A EJECUTAR:

```
import express from 'express'
import ProductosRoutes from './routers/productos.routes.js'

const app = express()

app.set('view engine', 'ejs')
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }))
app.use('/', express.static('public'))

app.use(ProductosRoutes)


app.listen(2022, function () {
    console.log('El servidor esta ON! http://localhost:2022')
})
```

ACA EL ERROR EN CUESTION:

```
E:\NANO\Estudios\DA VINCI\4 TO CUAT\Aplicaciones Híbridas\CLASES\Clase #08\expressServer.js:1
import express from 'express'
   ^^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
←[90m    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:872:18)←[39m
←[90m    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:947:10)←[39m
←[90m    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:32)←[39m
←[90m    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:703:12)←[39m
←[90m    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:999:10)←[39m
←[90m    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:11←[39m
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! mi-proyecto-lindo@1.0.0 server: `cls && node expressServer.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the mi-proyecto-lindo@1.0.0 server script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output 
above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Diego\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2022-09-16T22_34_11_562Z-debug.log
PS E:\NANO\Estudios\DA VINCI\4 TO CUAT\Aplicaciones Híbridas\CLASES\Clase #08>
```

Answer (score 0):

Si estás utilizando Node, hasta la versión actual no es posible utilizar el import, en su lugar se usa require.

**Por lo que la siguiente línea:**

```
import express from 'express'
```

**Debería escribirse de la siguiente manera:**

```
const express = require("express");
```

Lo mismo sucederá con la siguiente línea:

**Pasará de esto:**

```
import ProductosRoutes from './routers/productos.routes.js'
```

**A esto:**

```
const ProductosRoutes = require('./routers/productos.routes.js')
```

Comment: Estoy utilizando una version vieja de node porque tengo windows viejo que debo actualizar. Estoy usando la version 12.10.0. Con respecto a los import, en el package.json tengo indicado "type": "module" para que trabaje con los modulos de ES, y no con los de commonJS, que ahi si se usaban lo require. No se si puede haber incompatibilidades al usar los modulos de ES, con la version que tengo de node.

Comment: De hecho sí. Tiene que instalar babel para usar sintaxis ES6. +15 versión pude usar sin problema

Comment: En la versión actual de Node, se puede usar sentencias `import` (ver ["determinando el sistema de módulos"](https://nodejs.org/api/packages.html#determining-module-system)) simplemente añadiendo `"type": "module"` al archivo `package.json`, sin usar ningún otro flag o extensión adicional.

Comment: Espero estés utilizando la versión LTS que es la 16 y la recomendada por mismo Node, la otra aún no es una buena opción. Y en la 16 al menos de forma nativa no es posible utilizar la sintaxis del import.

Answer (score 0):

No necesitas cambiar nada del código, tal como te han explicado en otra respuesta, se trata de un problema de sintaxis. El programa que tu profesor ha escrito tiene una sintaxis no soportada por tu versión de NodeJS.

Una forma de resolver el problema es actualizar Node a la última versión, pero en caso de no poder hacerlo aún tienes la posibilidad de solucionarlo sin cambiar nada en el código, excepto un ajuste en el fichero `package.json`.

Por ejemplo, si ejecutas tu programa usando `npm start` o `npm run start`, debes editar dicho `script` para añadir el [soporte para módulos](https://2ality.com/2019/04/nodejs-esm-impl.html#using-es-modules-on-nodejs) en NodeJS v12:

```js
// fichero package.json
{
  //...
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node --experimental-modules expressServer.js"
  },
  //...
}
```

Como observas he añadido 2 cosas en el fichero `package.json`, la primera es para indicarle a Node que la resolución de dependencias se hará como módulos y la segunda es para activar esta característica en el motor, mediante el uso de:

```
--experimental-modules
```

Por otro lado, si tienes NodeJS v15 o posterior, puedes usar módulos de ES2015 sin necesidad de ningún flag adicional, pero debes decirle a Node que el sistema de módulos a usar será el de ES2015, manteniendo el valor `"type": "module"` en el archivo `package.json`.

Puedes consultar: ["determinando el sistema de módulos"](https://nodejs.org/api/packages.html#determining-module-system) en la documentación de la versión actual de NodeJS.

Espero que esto te ayude a resolver el problema.